# Custom slicing solution needed

Tags: g-code, slicing, extrusion

So I have a printer that I'm prototyping right now, and it's a little different; the Y-axis is a rotary drum.  To compare to a bed-slinger, instead of the surface traveling forward and backward, it rolls.  The issue this will create is not one that will instantly cause issues, but rather a few millimeters up when 1 mm of travel at the surface, is 2 mm of travel on the print.

While I'm not terribly concerned about the loss of resolution, I am quite concerned about under-extrusion on the Y-axis moves.  What I need is a way to incrementally increase the extrusion as the layers go up.  Something like x + (n * c), where 'x' is the amount of filament per unit at the base layer, 'n' is the number of layers beyond the base layer, and 'c' is the difference in circumference per layer, should do the job.  But the idea of manually adjusting the G-code layer by layer sounds about as much fun as a rock concert of nothing but fingernails on chalkboards and out-of-control ball-bearing tumblers...

Where should I start?

Comment: It may be helpful to [edit] in a photo or illustration of the printer in question.

Comment: So, you want cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: Agarza; Printer is still being made, and I'm waiting on parts, sorry.  But if you can imagine the planar build surface being replaced with a 70mm drum; You've got it~.

Comment: Perry; No, I don't need the coordinates.  Just to adjust the extrusion per layer in one (Y) direction.  Like I said, I'm not concerned about the resolution, just under-extrusion and having the coords isn't going to help me on that. As far as the printer will be concerned, and as far as the Slicer would be concerned, it'll "think" it's printing a planar object on a planar surface.  In fact, the gcode should be 100% compatible with a typical Ender-3 style bed-slinger and produce a fairly typical print... Other than a truely terrible finish due to what would then be over extrusion on the Y moves.